# Writing dynamic alerts in bootstrap by not putting any div's in the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can i write dynamic alerts in bootstrap

Below is the sample code i tried

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-current/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("<div/>").addClass("alert alert-error").html("test").alert();
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Have you already tried it by yourself?

Comment: That's part of the requirement and i tried with above code. I dont want to many bootstrap templates(divs) for modals/alerts in the page.

Comment: Have you already tried span elements?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create alerts dynamically. You need to change a few things in your code though.

```
$("<div/>").addClass("alert alert-danger").html("test").appendTo("yourSelector");
```

Check out [this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvgd5wes/4/)

This is pretty basic jQuery. You might want to find some tutorials online to work through.

Comment: He said without having any divs. You have a div.

Comment: @JordanD Ah, I missed that in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

## [LIVE_DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/9blHWUBZdx)

You can use three different `style class` here like `alert alert-success`,`alert alert-danger`,`alert alert-warning`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            ShowMessagesUsingPopup("alert", "alert alert-success");
        });



        function ShowMessagesUsingPopup(message, styleName) {

            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.id = "DivMessage";
            div.style.bottom = "10px";
            div.style.right = "25px";
            div.style.width = "400px";
            div.style.position = "fixed";
            div.style.zIndex = "1060";

            var spanTag = document.createElement('span');
            if (styleName == "alert alert-success") {
                spanTag.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok";
            }
            else if (styleName == "alert alert-danger") {
                spanTag.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle";
            }
            else if (styleName == "alert alert-warning") {
                spanTag.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign";
            }
            div.appendChild(spanTag);

            var buttonTag = document.createElement('button');
            buttonTag.type = "button";
            buttonTag.className = "close";
            buttonTag.textContent = "x";
            buttonTag.setAttribute("data-dismiss", "alert");
            div.appendChild(buttonTag);

            var strongTag = document.createElement('strong');
            strongTag.textContent = " " + message;
            div.appendChild(strongTag);

            div.style.display = "block";
            div.className = styleName + " alert-dismissable";
            $(".alert").alert();
            document.body.appendChild(div);

        }
```